# Redux: Can't figure out why ownProps gets out of sync with state

Tags: reactjs, redux

WHY? https://codepen.io/jamesplayer/project/editor/AjWvBb

I'm building a large Redux application and have managed to produce an error where a list item is being passed an id that no longer exists in the store, so when it goes to get the full object from the store it can't find it, causing an error that was apparently fixed in react-redux [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v3.0.0)

To reproduce requires a very specific sequence of components to do some mounting, dispatching, connecting and rendering so I've created an example of the issue in this codepen: https://codepen.io/jamesplayer/project/editor/AjWvBb

It seems that tweaking most things in this setup can fix the bug but I'm not exactly sure WHY this particular setup generates the issue. If someone could explain to me why this particular order of events creates the bug I'd really appreciate it, I've been trying to get to the bottom of it for a long time.

The basic structure looks like:

```
<Parent>

    <Page1 "I dispatch an action to clear out the list items every time I mount,
            then re-populate them after about 500ms">

        <Page1Wrapper "I'm connected to the store. I get an update when my child 
                       Page1Child1 mounts">

            <Child1 "I dispatch an action when I mount that can affect Page1Wrapper">

            <Child2 "I'm connected to the store, though in this example I don't receive any updates that would cause a 
                     re-render">

                <List "I get a list of ids from the store. I pass each id to a ListItem">

                    <ListItem "I'm connected to the store. I get passed an id from 
                               List and fetch the whole listItem object">

    <Page2 "I don't do much, but going from page1 to page2 and then back to page1 is 
            a good way to reproduce the error">
```

Comment: Oh man I thought I had it figured out but I was wrong. There's some very weird behavior going on and the Page1Child1 is part of the cause, I think there are some conflicting updates because if you either remove that child or set the same timeout as the parent in componentDidMount then everything works fine. I'm digging a bit deeper but it's quite a headache here!

Comment: @G4bri3l thanks for taking a look, yeah it's pretty crazy, changing the order of the two Child elements around also fixes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem

In `ConnectedList`, `state.listItems` was not empty, so `List` renders an instance of `ConnectedListItem`.

However, `state.listItems` was cleared by the `CLEAR_LIST_ITEMS` action right before `ConnectedListItem` could get it from the store, which causes it not to find any match from the now emptied `state.listItems`.

This bug requires very precise timing to reproduce, which might explain why changing things around fixes it (eg. if rendering of `ConnectedListItem` completes before `CLEAR_LIST_ITEMS`).

#### Solution

If you provide a default value to `listItem` (eg. `const ListItem = ({ listItem = {} })`), it will prevent the crash and `ConnectedList` will correctly re-render with the updated `state.listItems`.

I'd recommend not doing `state.listItems.map(listItem => listItem.id)` in `connect`, as it causes the component to always re-render, since a different array is constructed even if `state.listItems` didn't change. Mapping should be done in component or with [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) instead.

A cleaner approach is to pass the entire item to `ListItem`, eliminating the need for `ListItem` to be connected to the store:

```
const ListItem = ({ item }) => <li>{item.text}</li>;

const List = ({ listItems }) => (
  <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightgreen' }} className="border">
    I'm List and I get a list of ids from the store. I pass each id to a ListItem.
    <ul>{listItems.map(item => <ListItem key={item.id} item={item} />)}</ul>
  </div>
);

const ConnectedList = connect(state => ({
  listItems: state.listItems,
}))(List);
```

[image: Edit 417121z17]

Comment: thx for answering, have awarded bounty for your detailed answer, I guess we'll just have to put it down to "This bug requires very precise timing to reproduce". In reality I do use reselect to get the list of ids, but here I just wanted to create the simplest example of the problem, even though it's not that simple!